# How can I place an arrow at the bottom centre of section of each section?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for my "FINAL WEBPAGE" code to have two sections within the homepage. When the user clicks on the arrow down from section one on that same page it will bring them to section 2. From section two I will have an arrow which brings them back up to section one if the user clicks on it. I have already built the arrowing linking system. However, I cant see the arrows on the page?

How can I get the arrow down `<a href="#section two"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>` to be at the bottom centre of section one?

How can I get the arrow down `<a href="#section two"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>` to be at the bottom centre of section two?

**FINAL WEBPAGE**

```css
<style>

.anchorAwesome {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  top:190px;
  left:-23px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.anchorAwesome.FixPosition {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}

#contact-me {
  position: relative
}

#nav_a {
  width: 40%;
}

#nav_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
  }
}

.body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.nav.navbar-nav,
.nav.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.two {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#sections .section {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.hero {
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/38892/pexels-photo-38892.jpeg") center center no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60%;
}

.shape {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #4D5061;
  content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
  color: white;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 300px;
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -150px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.fa-angle-down {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.fa-angle-up {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.s1-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  top: 420px;
  left: -10px;
  right: 0px;
}

.s2-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  top: 450px;
  left: -10px;
  right: 0px;
}

.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#feedback-page {
  text-align: center;
}

#form-main {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

#form-div {
  background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.4);
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: -260px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}

.feedback-input {
  color: #3c3c3c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 0;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.feedback-input:focus {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0;
  border: 3px solid #3498db;
  color: #3498db;
  outline: none;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
}

.focused {
  color: #30aed6;
  border: #30aed6 solid 3px;
}

#name {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#name:focus {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 8px 5px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#email {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#email:focus {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#comment {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/comment.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150%;
  resize: vertical;
}

.input:hover,
textarea:hover,
.input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  background-color: white;
}

#button-blue {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: -4px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#button-blue:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #0493bd;
}

.submit:hover {
  color: #3498db;
}

.ease {
  width: 0px;
  height: 74px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.submit:hover .ease {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  #form-div {
    left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    width: 88%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
  }
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
        <a id="nav_a" class="navbar-brand pull-left" href=""><img id="nav_img" class="img-responsive" src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/logo1_zpsep8qps5m.png" alt="Logo design"></a>
        <h5 class="nav-title text-center center-block hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" id="nav-center">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
          <h5 class="nav-title text-center center-block hidden-xs ">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h5>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Unit 6</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#section3">Unit 14</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Unit 7</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Unit 1</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">CV</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Education</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="sections">
    <div class="section one" id="section_one">
      <div class="shape"></div>
      <div class="hero"></div>
      <h1 class="s1-text center-block">WELCOME TO MY</h1>
      <h1 class="s2-text center-block">PORTFOLIO</h1>
      <a href="#contact-me" class="anchorAwesome"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
    </div>
    <section id="contact-me" class="section two">
      <h2 class="s3-text">Click on the arrow to scroll down</h2>
      <h1 class="contact-title">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h1>
      <div id="form-main">
        <div id="form-div">
          <form class="form" id="form1">
            <p class="name">
              <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
            </p>
            <p class="email">
              <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
            </p>
            <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
            </p>
            <div class="submit">
              <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue" />
              <div class="ease"></div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <a href="#section_one" class="anchorAwesome"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
      </div>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#sections').fullpage();
        });
      </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your font asweome are not loading

Comment: Is it due to not being in the head part?

Comment: <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i> the fa class uses font awesome library..... I dont see  it anywhere in your html.. so thats the cause

Comment: I added it <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">. However, still doesn't show up?

Comment: Its not included.. href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css its an local path not online path.. So they are still not included

Comment: Still no doesn't show up.

Comment: Check the answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a fiddle.

> Here are the few bugs I have fixed.

**1. Linked FontAwesome correctly.**

**2. Corrected href link on top and bottom arrow.**

```css
.anchorAwesome {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.anchorAwesome.FixPosition {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}

#contact-me {
  position: relative
}

#nav_a {
  width: 40%;
}

#nav_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
  }
}

.body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.nav.navbar-nav,
.nav.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.two {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#sections .section {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.hero {
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/38892/pexels-photo-38892.jpeg") center center no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60%;
}

.shape {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #4D5061;
  content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
  color: white;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 300px;
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -150px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.fa-angle-down {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.fa-angle-up {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.s1-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  top: 420px;
  left: -10px;
  right: 0px;
}

.s2-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  top: 450px;
  left: -10px;
  right: 0px;
}

.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#feedback-page {
  text-align: center;
}

#form-main {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

#form-div {
  background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.4);
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: -260px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}

.feedback-input {
  color: #3c3c3c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 0;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.feedback-input:focus {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0;
  border: 3px solid #3498db;
  color: #3498db;
  outline: none;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
}

.focused {
  color: #30aed6;
  border: #30aed6 solid 3px;
}

#name {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#name:focus {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 8px 5px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#email {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#email:focus {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#comment {
  background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/comment.svg);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 11px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150%;
  resize: vertical;
}

.input:hover,
textarea:hover,
.input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  background-color: white;
}

#button-blue {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top: -4px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#button-blue:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #0493bd;
}

.submit:hover {
  color: #3498db;
}

.ease {
  width: 0px;
  height: 74px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.submit:hover .ease {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  #form-div {
    left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    width: 88%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
        <a id="nav_a" class="navbar-brand pull-left" href=""><img id="nav_img" class="img-responsive" src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/logo1_zpsep8qps5m.png" alt="Logo design"></a>
        <h5 class="nav-title text-center center-block hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" id="nav-center">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
          <h5 class="nav-title text-center center-block hidden-xs ">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h5>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Unit 6</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#section3">Unit 14</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Unit 7</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Unit 1</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">CV</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Education</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="sections">
    <div class="section one" id="section_one">
      <div class="shape"></div>
      <div class="hero"></div>
      <h1 class="s1-text center-block">WELCOME TO MY</h1>
      <h1 class="s2-text center-block">PORTFOLIO</h1>
      <a href="#contact-me" class="anchorAwesome"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
    </div>
    <section id="contact-me" class="section two">
      <h2 class="s3-text">Click on the arrow to scroll down</h2>
      <h1 class="contact-title">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h1>
      <div id="form-main">
        <div id="form-div">
          <form class="form" id="form1">
            <p class="name">
              <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
            </p>
            <p class="email">
              <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
            </p>
            <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
            </p>
            <div class="submit">
              <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue" />
              <div class="ease"></div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <a href="#section_one" class="anchorAwesome FixPosition"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
      </div>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#sections').fullpage();
        });
      </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cheers, I gave you the tick mark. How can I place these arrows at the bottom centre of each section? So arrown down at bottom centre of section one. Arrow up bottom centre of section 2.

Comment: The second answer isn't in the bottom centre? I adjust the first arrow to the bottom centre as both arrows where in the middle. However, I can't seem to move the section 2 arrow up to the centre bottom of the page. Check my updated post code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your anchor `href` for top and bottom links properly.

```css
 #nav_a {
      width:40%;
      }
      #nav_img {
      width:100%;
      height: 30px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      }
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translatex(-50%);
      }
      }
      .body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      color: black;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      height: 10vh;
      z-index: 100;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: right;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      }
      .dropdown-menu li {
      text-align: center;
      }
      .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
      color: white;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 9px;
      transition: all .2s;
      }
      .nav.navbar-nav,
      .nav.navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
      .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      }
      .section {
      min-height: 100vh;
      }
      .one {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .two {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      #sections .section {
      padding-top: 50px;
      }
      .hero {
      background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/38892/pexels-photo-38892.jpeg") center center no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 60%;
      }
      .shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: #4D5061;
      content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
      color: white;
      height: 300px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 300px;
      top: 15%;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -150px;
      z-index: 10;
      }
      .fa-angle-down {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      margin-bottom: auto;
    }

    .fa-angle-up {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      margin-bottom: auto;
    }
      .s1-text {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20pt;
      color: black;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      z-index: 99;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 60px;
      top:420px;
      left: -10px;
      right: 0px;
      }
      .s2-text {
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      font-size: 20pt;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      z-index: 99;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10px;
      top:450px;
      left: -10px;
      right: 0px;
      }
      .center-block {
      display: block;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 30px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      }
      @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
      #feedback-page{
      text-align:center;
      }
      #form-main{
      width:100%;
      float:left;
      padding-top:0px;
      }
      #form-div {
      background-color:rgba(72,72,72,0.4);
      padding-left:35px;
      padding-right:35px;
      padding-top:35px;
      padding-bottom:50px;
      width: 450px;
      float: left;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top:30px;
      margin-left: -260px;
      -moz-border-radius: 7px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
      }
      .feedback-input {
      color:#3c3c3c;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight:500;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-radius: 0;
      line-height: 22px;
      background-color: #fbfbfb;
      padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      width:100%;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
      }
      .feedback-input:focus {
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0;
      border: 3px solid #3498db;
      color: #3498db;
      outline: none;
      padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
      }
      .focused{
      color:#30aed6;
      border:#30aed6 solid 3px;
      }
      #name {
      background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-position: 11px 8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
      #name:focus {
      background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-position: 8px 5px;
      background-position: 11px 8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
      #email {
      background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-position: 11px 8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
      #email:focus {
      background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-position: 11px 8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
      #comment {
      background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/comment.svg);
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-position: 11px 8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
      .textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      line-height: 150%;
      resize:vertical;
      }
      .input:hover, textarea:hover,
      .input:focus, textarea:focus {
      background-color:white;
      }
      #button-blue {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      float:left;
      width: 100%;
      border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
      cursor:pointer;
      background-color: #3498db;
      color:white;
      font-size:24px;
      padding-top:22px;
      padding-bottom:22px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      margin-top:-4px;
      font-weight:700;
      }
      #button-blue:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
      color: #0493bd;
      }
      .submit:hover {
      color: #3498db;
      }
      .ease {
      width: 0px;
      height: 74px;
      background-color: #fbfbfb;
      -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
      -moz-transition: .3s ease;
      -o-transition: .3s ease;
      -ms-transition: .3s ease;
      transition: .3s ease;
      }
      .submit:hover .ease {
      width:100%;
      background-color:white;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
      #form-div {
      left: 3%;
      margin-right: 3%;
      width: 88%;
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-left: 3%;
      padding-right: 3%;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
      
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a id="nav_a" class="navbar-brand pull-left" href=""><img id="nav_img" class="img-responsive" src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/logo1_zpsep8qps5m.png" alt="Logo design"></a>
               <h5 class="nav-title text-center center-block hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" id="nav-center">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                  <h5 class="nav-title text-center center-block hidden-xs ">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h5>
               </ul>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Unit 6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">Unit 14</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Unit 7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Unit 1</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">CV</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Education</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div id="sections">
      <div class="section one" id="section_one">
         <div class="shape"></div>
         <div class="hero"></div>
         <h1 class="s1-text center-block">WELCOME TO MY</h1>
         <h1 class="s2-text center-block">PORTFOLIO</h1>
         <a href="#contact-me"> To section Two<i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
      </div>
      <section id="contact-me" class="section two">
      <h2 class="s3-text">Click on the arrow to scroll down</h2>
      <h1 class="contact-title">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h1>
      <div id="form-main">
         <div id="form-div">
            <form class="form" id="form1">
               <p class="name">
                  <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
               </p>
               <p class="email">
                  <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
               </p>
                  <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
               </p>
               <div class="submit">
                  <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
                  <div class="ease"></div>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
         <a href="#section_one">To section one <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
      </div>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#sections').fullpage();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```